# Adding another intent

Tags: android

So situation is I have this button that will call the following function to allow you to select an app as the source (Camera and Gallery applications). However, I'd like to add another that I've created that will select from google Images. I have all the working code to get the google images but how do I add it to this list? I've been looking in all the wrong places. Any direction would help!

```
private static void openImageIntent(Activity a) {
    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
    root.mkdirs();
    final String fname = "photo";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = a.getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }    

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

        a.startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GALLERY_PIC_REQUEST);

    }
```

[image]

-------------------------EDIT---------------------------
I got it!

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.projectCaruso.imagesearch.ImageGridActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: "However, I'd like to add another that I've created that will select from google Images" - You want to add another what?

Comment: Option to the Select Source

Comment: So have you made use of an intent filter to register for events related to image file types? Chris' answer is correct if that is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not an expert in this area, but I think you will find your answer in the samples listed here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Storage

In short, you need to expand the manifest for your custom 'Google Images-activity' to react to the action and data mime type of the `Intent` you are creating. Maybe it could look something like this, but again: I'm not an expert, havn't tried this yet myself:

```
<activity ...>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <data android:type="image/*" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The documentation states that you cannot implement this without the `OPENABLE` category, which forces you to make the file available through a special `ContentProvider` that "supports `OpenableColumns` and `ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor()`". Actually, you might need to write some glue code to comply with this requirement.

Comment: I tried using that in my manifest and got 'error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'type' with value 'Image/*').'